# Spark reading table after connection to HiverServer2 only gives schema not data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I try to connect to a remote hive cluster using the following code and I get the table data as expected

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("adhocattempts")
  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://<remote-host>:9083")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
val seqdf=sql("select * from anon_seq")
seqdf.show
```

However, when I try to do this via HiveServer2, I get no data in my dataframe. This table is based on a sequencefile. Is that the issue, since I am actually trying to read this via jdbc?

```
val sparkJdbc = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkHiveJob").getOrCreate
val sc = sparkJdbc.sparkContext
val sqlContext = sparkJdbc.sqlContext
val driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
Class.forName(driverName)
val df = sparkJdbc.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://<remote-host>:10000/default")
  .option("dbtable", "anon_seq")

  .load()
df.show()
```

Can someone help me understand the purpose of using HiveServer2 with jdbc and relevant drivers in Spark2?

Comment: Did you find a solution?